# How to know the value of record and field in an app package when running app engine?

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplecode, peoplesoft-app-engine

So I have this Application Engine that calls on this Application Package, this application package has a `CreateSql(Select...)` statement, and some of the records and fields are dynamic.

My question is -- how can i possibly know what value does these dynamic records and fields holds?

I tried doing a `MessageBox` on the application package but it does not show in the message logs in the Application Engine.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Hi Peter, im sorry, i thought I already went back to that question. Ill go back to it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use MessageBox in an Application Engine, the message should appear in the stdout file. This file is formatted as follows:

```
AE_(appEngine name)_(process instance).stdout
```

This file should be visible via Process Monitor > Details > View Log/Trace. The messages in this file also get sent to Process Monitor > Details > Message Log. The only reason it doesn't appear there, is if you explicitly change the Output destination via ProcessRequest/SCHED_INFO/ReportDefn class. If not, your configuration is messed up.

If you can't get this to work, an option would be to setup your own logging:

```
Local string &sFileLoc = "C:\TEMP"; /* File location */
Local File &fileLog = GetFile(&sFileLoc , "A", %Exec_Synchronous + %FilePath_Absolute);
Local SQL &oSQL = CreateSQL("Select ...");

&fileLog.WriteLine("LOG FOR SQL STRING: " | &oSQL.Value);
While &oSQL.Fetch(&oOut)
/* Handle row returned by &oSQL */ 
    &fileLog.WriteLine("...");
End-While;
&fileLog.WriteLine();
&fileLog.Close();
```